# Total Liquidity Calculation going wrong in specific situations

Tags: nodejs, uniswap, ethers.js

I cant really figure out how to phrase the question, but essentially the situation is:

I use this code to calculate total liquidity:

```
//Contracts instantiation is class object constructor (I use class objects to store pair information)
this._pair_contract = new ethers.Contract(
    this._address,
    pair_abi_template,
    account
);
this._token0contract = new ethers.Contract(
    this._token0,
    abi_template,
    account
);
this._token1contract = new ethers.Contract(
    this._token1,
    abi_template,
    account
);

async function get_ftm_price(){
    const ftmreserves =await FTMUSD.getReserves();
    let ftmres0 = ftmreserves._reserve0.toString();
    ftmres0 = ftmres0.substring(0, ftmres0.length - 6) + '.' + ftmres0.substring(ftmres0.length - 6, 0);
    let ftmres1 = ftmreserves._reserve1.toString();
    ftmres1 = ftmres1.substring(0, ftmres1.length - 18) + '.' + ftmres1.substring(ftmres1.length - 18, 0);
    ftmres0 = Number(ftmres0);
    ftmres1 = Number(ftmres1);
    let FTM_price = ftmres0 / ftmres1;
    return FTM_price;
}

async liquidity(){
        let FTM_price = await get_ftm_price();
        const reserves = await this._pair_contract.getReserves();
        const tok0dec = await this._token0contract.decimals();
        const tok1dec = await this._token1contract.decimals();
        this._tok0dec = tok0dec;
        this._tok1dec = tok1dec;
        if (tok0dec <= 0 || tok1dec <= 0){
            botsend('token decimal == 0'); //I have a telegram bot, "botsend" function is just a function sending a message 
            return -1.0;
        }
        let reserve0 = reserves._reserve0.toString();
        let reserve1 = reserves._reserve1.toString();
        reserve0 = reserve0.substring(0, reserve0.length - tok0dec) + '.' + reserve0.substring(reserve0.length - tok0dec, reserve0.length);
        reserve1 = reserve1.substring(0, reserve1.length - tok1dec) + '.' + reserve1.substring(reserve1.length - tok1dec, reserve1.length);
        reserve0 = Number(reserve0);
        reserve1 = Number(reserve1);
        let valueFTM = reserve0 / reserve1;
        let valueUSD = FTM_price * valueFTM;
        this._price = valueUSD;
        let poolone = 0.0;
        let pooltwo = 0.0;
        if (this._token0 == addresses.WFTM){
            poolone = reserve0 * FTM_price;
            pooltwo = reserve1 * valueUSD;
        }
        else if (this._token1 == addresses.WFTM){
            poolone = reserve0 * valueUSD;
            pooltwo = reserve1 * FTM_price;
        }
        const pooltotal = poolone + pooltwo;
        this._liquidity = pooltotal;  
        return pooltotal;
    }
```

The problem I am experiencing is, when the pair is format is like this "WFTM/sometoken" the total liquidity calculation works perfectly.
But when the format is like "sometoken/WFTM" I get a crazy massive value that is nowhere near the actual total liquidity.

Does anyone know whats going on here? Like I said, it works like a charm until the format is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line needs to be reversed if the pair format is reversed.

```
let valueFTM = reserve0 / reserve1;
```

Maybe `get_ftm_price` also.

Comment: Oh wow thats makes sense, can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!! will accept as answer and then update when fully tested